# Backgrounding a process after writing to its stdin

Tags: python, linux, bash, init, zombie-process

I am using linux/cpython 3.3/bash. Here's my problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, DEVNULL
import time

s = Popen('cat', stdin=PIPE, stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL)
s.stdin.write(b'helloworld')
s.stdin.close()
time.sleep(1000)     #doing stuff
```

This leaves `cat` as a zombie (and I'm busy "doing stuff" and can't `wait` on the child process). Is there a way in bash that I can wrap `cat` (e.g. through creating a grand-child) that would allow me to write to `cat`'s stdin, but have init take over as the parent? A python solution would work too, and I can also use nohup, disown etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the subprocess from another process whose only task is to wait on it.

```
pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
     s = Popen('cat', stdin=PIPE, stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL)
     s.stdin.write(b'helloworld')
     s.stdin.close()
     s.wait()
     sys.exit()
time.sleep(1000)
```

Comment: this solves the problem of a zombie `cat` - however I now have a zombie python process instead. i like this style though, and a separate thread for waiting would work...but I am still hoping there is some clever bash one-liner out there.

Comment: `bash` actually has nothing to do with this. Since you aren't using `shell=True`, the call to `Popen` is executing the `cat` command directly.

Comment: agreed, i know that i'm not using bash currently, but if there is a way to use redirects/subshells in bash (and yes you'd have to specify `shell=True` and, to be safe, `executable` too) which solves my problem, i am happy to do that

Comment: Not that I know of. Unless you have a lot of zombie processes filling up the process table, this really isn't a problem, though. However, it's hard to suggest a good alternative without knowing what the subprocess is actually doing, or what you're doing afterwards that prevents you from waiting on it.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround might be to "daemonize" your cat: fork, then quickly fork again and exit in the 2nd process, with the 1st one wait()ing for the 2nd. The 3rd process can then exec() `cat`, which will inherit its file descriptors from its parent. Thus you need to create a pipe first, then close stdin in the child and dup() it from the pipe.

I don't know how to do these things in python, but I'm fairly certain it should be possible.